# JavaScript slice() is not deleting elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

```
while (j<secondSpecsArr.length) {
    console.log(j);
    if (regStr.test(secondSpecsArr[j])){
        console.log('slice operation' + j + ' ' + secondSpecsArr[j]);
        secondSpecsArr.slice(j,1); 
    } else { j++; }
}
```

I am deleting elements from Array, that include string 'strong'.
But it`s not deleting at least anything!
Like,`console.log('slice operation' + j + ' ' + secondSpecsArr[j]);` is working, but slice() isn'nt, and I get old array after this. Where's the problem?

Comment: can you plese provide an example of console.log(secondSpecsArr);

Comment: 30
slice operation30 <strong>DVD+R</strong> : 16X<br>

Comment: [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice): _"The slice() method **returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object** selected from begin to end (end not included). **The original array will not be modified.**"_

Comment: `slice` did not change your array. Use `splice` instead.

Comment: secondSpecsArr = secondSpecsArr.slice(j,1) maybe you are missing this

Comment: Yeah,my bad, thanks!

Comment: If it's not working please read the documentation for the methods used ***before*** asking questions here. Basic research is expected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is what `slice` is for. It doesn't remove from the array, it extracts. `splice` is removing from the array.

```
var a = [1,2,3];

a.slice(0,1) // [1]
//a = [1,2,3]

a.splice(0,1) // [1];
// a = [2,3]
```

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control)

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example)